# magento 2 How to customize product list pages of all subcategories under specific category?

Tags: magento2, category, category-products, customize

I want to customize all subcategory pages whose parent category is 'Services'. 
The customization includes following:

1. Remove Toolbar
2. Add filter for gender (gender is product attribute)
3. Add custom blocks
4. Display category filter instead of layered navigation.
5. Move layered navigation on the right under specific div

I tried to achieve most of the above using layout 'catalog_category_view_id_{{id}}.xml'. However the layout is not applicable to subcategories.

Please guide me in the right direction.